# JavaScript Unshift EACH array element

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, knockout.js

I have two arrays that contain objects. `arr1` and `arr2`. If I unshift `arr1` to contain the elements of `arr2`, the elements are not appended individually into `arr1`, instead the whole array (`arr2`) is appended at the beginning, for example:

```
arr1 = [{ele:1}, {ele:2}]
arr2 = [{ele:3}, {ele:4}]
```

I get: `arr1 = [[{ele:3}, {ele:4}], {ele:1}, {ele:2}]`

*Notice the whole array inside instead of its objects.*

I want: `arr1 = [{ele:3}, {ele:4}, {ele:1}, {ele:2}]`

My arrays are ko.observableArray(), maybe that makes a difference?

Comment: Well, unshift simply prepends the value to the array. If you unshift an array you simply insert the array as first element.

Comment: @FelixKling is there another way to append all the elements of an array in the other without looping?

Comment: Yes, as Mr. X showed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There you go:

`[].unshift.apply(arr1, arr2);`

Comment: Excellent answer, you must see this documentation [JS Apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply)

Comment: An explanation would make the answer more useful for the OP and future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

maybe this might be bit simpler

```
let arr1 = [{ ele: 1 }, { ele: 2 }];
let arr2 = [{ ele: 3 }, { ele: 4 }];
for (const iterator of arr2) {
  arr1.unshift(iterator);
}
```